# How can we convert a SourceRecord in Kafka Connect to AVRO?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I have a use-case where I need to convert a `SourceRecord` to a `GenericRecord`. Can someone help me how to do that?

Basically, I'm writing a custom Kafka Producer and embed that in the Connect runtime code. When the `producer.send()` is called, the SourceRecord gets converted to a `ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>` type. Now, from this, how do I get a `GenericRecord` so I can perform my custom tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Look at Confluent `AvroData` class in the schema registry repo. There is some method in there to/from Connect Data Schema/Struct classes (which are embedded in a SourceRecord's key/value)